# Space too log between cal letter and index

Tags: math-mode, spacing, mathcal

The code `${\cal T\!}_{\!j}$` produces the output :
[image]

and as you can see, the space between the two characters is too large. How can I reduce this space ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
${\cal T\!}_{\!j}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: What about `$\mathcal{T}_j$`?

Comment: This was actually a bug :-) It's fixed in LaTeX-dev which should be out with TeXLive 2020, and will be in the fall release of LaTeX (October). Though `\cal` is a legacy command and you should use `\mathcal` regardless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the command `\mathcal`, not `\cal`. If you still think the space is too large with `\mathcal`, you can add negative spacing in the subscript with `\!`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fourier}
\begin{document}
\({\cal T}_j\)

\({\cal T\!}_{\!j}\)

\(\mathcal{T}_j\)

\(\mathcal{T}_{\!j}\)

\(\mathcal{T}_{\!\!j}\)
\end{document}
```

[image]